# How to create a UIView bounce animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiview, uikit

I have the following CATransition for a UIView called `finalScoreView`, which makes it enter the screen from the top:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.duration = 0.2;
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

[gameOver.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];
[finalScoreView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];
```

How do I make it so it bounces once after it comes down, then stays still?  It should still enter the screen from the top but then bounce when it comes down.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you targeting iOS7 and above? If so, you could leverage UIKit Dynamics

Answer (score 147, accepted):

With iOS7 and UIKit Dynamics, there is no longer any need to use `CAKeyframeAnimations` or `UIView` animations!

Take a look at [Apple's UIKit Dynamics Catalog app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html). Alternately, [Teehanlax has a clear, concise tutorial](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uikit-dynamics/) with the [full project in github](https://github.com/TeehanLax/UIKit-Dynamics-Example). If you want a more detailed tutorial about the ins-and-outs of dynamics, the [Ray Winderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial) is great. As always, the Apple docs are a great first stop, so check out the [UIDynamicAnimator Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the docs.

Here's a bit of the code from the Teenhanlax tutorial:

```
self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = 
                [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.redSquare]];
[self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];
    
UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = 
                [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.redSquare]]; 
collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
[self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];
    
UIDynamicItemBehavior *elasticityBehavior = 
                [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.redSquare]];
elasticityBehavior.elasticity = 0.7f;
[self.animator addBehavior:elasticityBehavior];
```

And here are the results

[image: Square bounce]

UIKit Dynamics is a really powerful and easy to use addition to iOS7 and you can get some great looking UI from it.

Other examples:

[image: Button bounce]

[image: Slide bounce]

[image: Springy collection]

[image: WWDC spring collection]

The steps to implement UIKit dynamics is always the same:

1. Create a `UIDynamicAnimator` and store it in a strong property
2. Create one or more `UIDynamicBehaviors`. Each behavior should have one or more items, typically a view to animate.
3. Make sure that the initial state of the items used in the `UIDynamicBehaviors` is a valid state within the `UIDynamicAnimator` simulation.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks so much for your help!  This definitely looks extremely easy to do!  I tried it and it works when it hits the bottom of the view, but it doesn't work with another view - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895674/uidynamicanimator-wont-work-with-uiview-but-will-with-self-view - I would love if you could help me out there!  :)  Thanks

Comment: A MAGNIFICENT tutorial BUT you'd just use one line of code, usingSpringWithDamping, for a bounce !

Comment: Can you share some code sample for the Uitableview  bounce animation as above. I am trying with UITableview but not sure from where to start.

Comment: UIKit Dynamics is great when you deal with example cases. But when it comes to real tasks, you see how raw and restricted is it. One big problem is overriding of `UIDynamicItemBehavior` (which is actually properties, not behavior). You can't just use different physical properties in different behaviors. Another case is implementing UIScrollView-like rubber bounds - it's very complicated. I can write even more but comment is too short.

Comment: add full code please. Your code describes how to create `UIDynamicAnimator` and objects associated with it but doesn't answer how to use them

Comment: Yes, I didn't find this answer helpful because it's too exploratory and doesn't focus on the desired task of simply adding bounce to a UIView.  I'm not interested in finding out what I can do, but rather how to solve the specific problem.

Answer (score 273):

A simpler alternative to `UIDynamicAnimator` in iOS 7 is Spring Animation (a new and powerful UIView block animation), which can give you nice bouncing effect with damping and velocity:
**Objective C**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
  delay:delay
  usingSpringWithDamping:damping
  initialSpringVelocity:velocity
  options:options animations:^{
    //Animations
    }
  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Completion Block
}];
```

**Swift**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
     delay: delay,
     usingSpringWithDamping: damping,
     initialSpringVelocity: velocity,
     options: options,
     animations: {
            //Do all animations here
            }, completion: {
            //Code to run after animating
                (value: Bool) in
        })
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:duration,
     delay: delay,
     usingSpringWithDamping: damping,
     initialSpringVelocity: velocity,
     options: options,
     animations: {
            //Do all animations here
            }, completion: {
            //Code to run after animating
                (value: Bool) in
        })
```

`usingSpringWithDamping`  0.0 == very bouncy. 1.0 makes it smoothly decelerate without overshooting.

`initialSpringVelocity` is, roughly, "desired distance, divided by desired seconds".  1.0 corresponds to the total animation distance traversed in one second. Example, total animation distance is 200 points and you want the start of the animation to match a view velocity of 100 pt/s, use a value of 0.5.

More detailed tutorial and sample app can be found in this [tutorial](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions--more). I hope this is useful for someone.

Comment: Here is a demo project I created to help you get the animation just right. Enjoy! https://github.com/jstnheo/SpringDampingDemo

Comment: Cheers for that demo project, mate. Really helps figure these values out since they are quite obtuse. I wish Apple had made them clearer

Comment: My only problem with this is that it will go past the point I want it to go. At least when I'm animating the height

Answer (score 35):

Here is a demo project I created to help you get the animation just right. Enjoy!

[SpringDampingDemo](https://github.com/jstnheo/SpringDampingDemo)

[image]

Comment: Cheers for that demo project, mate. Really helps figure these values out since they are quite obtuse. I wish Apple had made them clearer

Answer (score -1):

```
- (IBAction)searchViewAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
  if(sender.tag == 0)
  {
    sender.tag = 1;

    CGRect optionsFrame2 = self.defaultTopView.frame;
    optionsFrame2.origin.x = -320;

    CGRect optionsFrame = self.searhTopView.frame;
    optionsFrame.origin.x = 320;
    self.searhTopView.frame = optionsFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:0 animations:^{

        CGRect optionsFrame = self.searhTopView.frame;

        optionsFrame.origin.x = 0;
        self.searhTopView.frame = optionsFrame;
        self.defaultTopView.frame = optionsFrame2;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];        
}
else
{
    sender.tag = 0;

    CGRect optionsFrame2 = self.defaultTopView.frame;
    optionsFrame2.origin.x = 0;

    CGRect optionsFrame = self.searhTopView.frame;
    optionsFrame.origin.x = 320;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:0 animations:^{

        CGRect optionsFrame = self.searhTopView.frame;

        optionsFrame.origin.x = 320;
        self.searhTopView.frame = optionsFrame;
        self.defaultTopView.frame = optionsFrame2;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
}
```

Comment: There are no explanation in the code and no comment. This is not helpful