# UIDynamicAnimator - won't work with UIView but will with Self.View?

Tags: iphone, animation, view, uiview

I used this code from Apple's sample app and adjusted it to mine.  I want the UIImageView `gameOverFalling` to run this method (fall and kind of bounce).  It should collide with the UIView `finalScoreView`, as you can see in line 2.

```
-(void)gameOverFallingMethod{
    UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:finalScoreView];

    UIGravityBehavior *gravityBeahvior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.gameOverFalling]];
    [animator addBehavior:gravityBeahvior];

    UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.gameOverFalling]];
    // Apple said: "Creates collision boundaries from the bounds of the dynamic animator's
    // reference view (self.view)."
    collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = self;
    [animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];

    self.animator = animator;
}
```

However when I run my app, it returns a Thread 1: SIGABRT error.  In the console:

> ```
> View item (<UIImageView: 0x10aaa0c70; frame = (15 175; 288 42);
>   autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10aa7e0a0>>)
> should be a descendant of reference view in <UIDynamicAnimator: 0x10ae17610>
> Stopped (0.000000s) in <UIView: 0x10aa9e1e0> {{0, 0}, {288, 195}}
> ```

It works when I replace 'finalScoreView' on line 2 with 'self.view', but then it falls to the bottom of the whole screen.

Any ideas what I did wrong?  I would love to know, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears from the exception that `self.gameOverFalling` does not descend from `finalScoreView` in your view hierarchy.  See the quote from [UIDynamicAnimator class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> To animate views, create an animator with the initWithReferenceView:
>   method. The coordinate system of the reference view serves as the
>   coordinate system for the animator’s behaviors and items. Each dynamic
>   item you associate with this sort of animator must be a UIView object
>   and must descend from the reference view.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding to subview before adding any behaviour.

```
addSubview(square)
var gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [square])
gravity.magnitude = gravitySpeed
animator.addBehavior(gravity)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to add your items to the reference view using:

```
finalScoreView.addSubview(self.gameOverFalling)
```