# IOS UIView Bounce Animation

Tags: ios, physics-engine, uidynamicanimator

I have a `UIVIew` (container) and another `UIView` (box) the box view is inside of the `ContainerView`. When a `UIButton` is pressed I would like the box view to drop down off the bottom of the screen, and bounce with 10px left; then once the bouncing has stopped I still want the box to have 10px showing. Here is some sample code of from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892105/how-to-create-a-uiview-bounce-animation):

```
UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self]; //self is the container

UIGravityBehavior* gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[box]];
[animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];

UICollisionBehavior* collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[reportBar.bar]];
collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
[animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];

UIDynamicItemBehavior *elasticityBehavior =
[[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[box]];
elasticityBehavior.elasticity = 0.7f;
[animator addBehavior:elasticityBehavior];
```

The code is running when it should but the box isn't dropping.

[image: example of layout]

Edit 1:

- Self refers to the container UIView
- I have also tried changing self for the currentViewController.view, no change.

Edit 2:

- all of this code is inside the container view implementation file.

Comment: UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self]; , what is self here? if you have written this code in controller it will be UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

Comment: self is the container; added it in a comment in the code.

Comment: The code that you posted is that inside of the containerView implementation?

Comment: Yes, all of the code is inside the container view .m

Comment: Shouldn't this code be inside of the veiwcontroller and then you will reference the containerView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give a try to make animator property,

```
@property UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
```

and then your code,

```
_animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];

 ...
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works, and why it didn't work before. Also thanks a ton for this.

Comment: I guess issue was with instance variable, animator could not communicate with iOS physics engine. Alternatively if we make animator  globally accessible then also it will work.. UIDynamicAnimator *animator; and then referring it by self.animator

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't specify the correct reference view.  It should be either `self.view` or `self.containerView`

```
UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];
```

Update
I think you should put the code in the ViewController for this scene and as @BaSha suggested create a animator property and after a button click you will add the behavior and will reference `self.containerView`
Just make sure that boxView is inside of the containerView

Comment: self is the container view, so I think just self will work. Should I pass in another value or property?

Comment: Self.view , when you are inside of a view controller, returns the UIView of the view controler. self is the UIView, and if I try and use self.view I get an error.

Comment: Changing the animator to a property fixed it, but how can I have the box drop partially out of the reference view?

Comment: @AlexPelletier : i guess you may have to set custom boundary for that instead collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet can provide **BOUNCE EFFECT** on your views.

```
CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];</br>
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:y-position1]];   
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:y-position2]];
[animation setDuration:.7];    //   time gap between the bounces
animation.repeatCount=500;    //    no:of times bounce effect has to be done 
[YOURVIEW.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"somekey"];
```

Comment: The above code is to implement Vertical Bounce effect. To make it a horizontal bounce effect,just change the 1st 3 lines as:                                              
CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];                        
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x-position1]]; 
  
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x-position2]];