# Animating the heigh of a UIButton with UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm building an app where I want a kind of reverse pull-to-refresh. There's no tableView involved but I would like to pull a UIButton to increase it's height and animate the label and other properties like the backgroundColor simultaneously - achieving the same effect seen with pull-to-refresh. I also need that rebound/bounce effect to emulate gravity.

**A very good example of the desired behaviour is the iOS action center**

One idea was to link the animateWithDuration of UIView up to a UIGestureRecognizer:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: delay: usingSpringWithDamping: initialSpringVelocity: options: animations: completion:nil]
```

I'm using storyboards and autolayout.
What would be the best approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using autolayouts?

Comment: @YuviGr yes, I'm using autolayout

Comment: @YuviGr A very good example of the desired behaviour is the iOS action center

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the height `constraint` of your button.

If you don't have any reference to it, you can control-drag it to your `ViewController`, Like so

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonHeight;
```

Once you have this you can change the buttons height according to the user pan gesture. Just add the `gestureRecogniser` to the View

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userPulledDown:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

in the gesture method

```
- (void)userPulledDown:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  switch (gesture.state){
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
       // the user has started to pull the view
       break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
       // create the animation of the button (using the constraint) & other views
       break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
       // clean-up after the user released the gesture
       break;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You i would recommend calling the method `translationInView:` in `UIPanGestureRecognizer` this method returns a CGPoint (x,y) of the panGesture in the view you gave it.

But you really need to read the documentation of [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html) & [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html) to really understand and to get better at coding in iOS

**EDIT2**

Bounce effect

check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892105/how-to-create-a-uiview-bounce-animation)

Comment: I'm getting the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'Began' - do I need to import something or conform to something?

Comment: what property off the UIGestureRecognizer should I use to change the constant property of a constraint?

Comment: check out my edit, like i said check the docs in the link i gave you. This will help you

Comment: I've read it but I don't see the full picture and I don't know how to go about creating that bounce effect