# What are some cool animations that I can do with UIWebView and UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

```
detailsView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1,0.1,1)
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        self.detailsView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1,1,1)
    })
```

I have tried this one, which zooms, some thing like when an App is opened.

I want something which can slide from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look here, [How to create a UIView bounce animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892105/how-to-create-a-uiview-bounce-animation) and here, https://github.com/pdetagyos/CoolUIViewAnimations