# how to do UIView Intrective Animation in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation, uiviewanimationtransition, uiviewanimation-curve

i want do Animation just Like same as Below Link:

https://dribbble.com/shots/4853929-View-Photos

i also tried many 3rd party Library but am not getting exactly animation just like  Above Link.

```
var rotationAndPerspectiveTransform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
        rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -10000.0
        rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, -.pi * 0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 0.1)

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeCubic, animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {

                self.customHeader?.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
                self.customHeader?.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
            }
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                self.customHeader?.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
                self.customHeader?.layer.transform =  CATransform3DIdentity

            }

        }, completion: nil)
```

some body help me to solve it.

Or suggest me any 3rd party Library.

Comment: see this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892105/how-to-create-a-uiview-bounce-animation

Comment: try this with some modification : https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection

Comment: @jatin patel, i already used that animation in my app for another viewcontroller but i need exact animation.