# How to create bouncing effect in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, bounce

I have created a popup in swift using UIView and I want to bounce it when displaying, but I don't know how to do that. I want to make the same effect as seen below:

[image]

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892105/how-to-create-a-uiview-bounce-animation

Answer (score 1):

You should use UIView.animate with usingSpringWithDamping and initialSpringVelocity parameters.
Eg:

```
// Change position of view
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    // Call layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Or you can change view's position in animation completion block. But it's not recommended.